Cannot use Cpp Library on ESP32 PlatformIO
This question is specific to PlatformIO extension
I am working on a little project in which I use an ESP32 to send me an email with the weather report every mornings.
I already took care of the email part and the Wifi one but I cannot fix the issue I get when I call the API that I am using to get the weather report.
I am using a wrapper for meteosource API : https://github.com/Meteosource/meteosource_cpp
My issue is coming from my libraries, it was a mess because of PlatformIO not having the basic libraries so I did add them in the lib Folder ( I used cp to copy every libraries from /usr/include/linux_x86.. to my lib in my project ). For my weather lib, I did add it like this

I then call the API as shown in the example of the repo :
const std::string api_key = "MY_API_KEY";
const std::string tier = "free";
Meteosource m = Meteosource(api_key, tier);

( My API Key is working, I've tried the same code on my laptop and it's working all right).
But when I try to build, I get this nasty error :
Building in release mode
Compiling .pio\build\nodemcu-32s\src\main.cpp.o
Linking .pio\build\nodemcu-32s\firmware.elf
c:/users/thomm/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcu-32s\lib266\libWeather_Bib.a(RequestHandler.cpp.o):(.literal._ZN14RequestHandlerC2ENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x0): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
c:/users/thomm/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcu-32s\lib266\libWeather_Bib.a(RequestHandler.cpp.o):(.literal._ZN14RequestHandlerC2ENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x4): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
c:/users/thomm/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcu-32s\lib266\libWeather_Bib.a(RequestHandler.cpp.o):(.literal._ZN14RequestHandlerD2Ev+0x0): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
c:/users/thomm/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcu-32s\lib266\libWeather_Bib.a(RequestHandler.cpp.o): in function `RequestHandler::RequestHandler(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
C:\Users\thomm\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\ESP32_HelloWorld/lib/Weather_Bib/src/RequestHandler.cpp:32: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
c:/users/thomm/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\thomm\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\ESP32_HelloWorld/lib/Weather_Bib/src/RequestHandler.cpp:33: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
c:/users/thomm/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\thomm\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\ESP32_HelloWorld/lib/Weather_Bib/src/RequestHandler.cpp:34: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
c:/users/thomm/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\thomm\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\ESP32_HelloWorld/lib/Weather_Bib/src/RequestHandler.cpp:35: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
c:/users/thomm/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcu-32s\lib266\libWeather_Bib.a(RequestHandler.cpp.o): in function `RequestHandler::~RequestHandler()':
C:\Users\thomm\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\ESP32_HelloWorld/lib/Weather_Bib/src/RequestHandler.cpp:41: undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\nodemcu-32s\firmware.elf] Error 1

So, It cannot access curl_easy_init() but Curl.h is in the lib folder ( and Easy.h is right next to it using EXTERN so it should be working ), I include it as such in RequestHandler.cpp and RequestHandler.h :
#include "Lin_bibs/curl/curl.h"

Here is the tree of all libraries imported from linux ( Dir only ) :

Here is a picture of curl tree :

I hope you can help me solving this.

There seem to be two misunderstandings here 1) To use a third party library (curl in this case) you need the header file curl.h and you need the library file (perhaps libcurl.a but that's a guess). You have the header file but you seem to have ignored the library file. You need to tell the linker to link with this library. 2) Don't copy libraries to your project. I have no idea why newbies do this. Leave the libraries where they are and tell your compiler and linker where to find them. This is not only less effort, it's also more likely to work.

Thank you, that would have been way easier but I am having trouble finding where PlatformIO is taking the libraries from and tell ihim where to find them...

OK, I've no idea about PlatformIO, I assumed it was another library but I see now it's another IDE. Anyways, one way or another, you have to tell it to pick up the curl library, not just the header file.

Yeah, I found a library which is specifically made to import curl to platform IO (I find it funny to have a library to find a library but anyway ). But It's not working either, I think I'll migrate to arduino IDE
